# Simple question on foreach loop question with array with 2 variables. (with code)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, json

How can I edit this foreach loop so that I will be able to use `strpos` to look if `q` is found in the `label` ? 
The result array will contain those values.

`$q` may be `anna` or `ann` or `reas john`

```
<?php

$q = $_GET["q"];
if (!$q) return;

$data = Array(
    Array(
        'label' => 'anna c13',
        'category' => 'Products'
    ),
    Array(
        'label' => 'anders andersson',
        'category' => 'People'
    ),
    Array(
        'label' => 'andreas johnson',
        'category' => 'People'
    )
);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    array_push($result, array(
        "label" => $value["label"],
        "category" => $value["category"]
    ));
}


$json = json_encode($result);

echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't work because `$key` contains a numeric index and `$value` contains an array. But, I'm not sure what you're trying to do? Convert a list of `labels` and `categories` into a JSON of `names` and `emails`? Where are the email address supposed to come from?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How should the `$result` array look like?

Comment: Excuse me, I have updated my question for better understanding. The result array must contain those values that `q` is found in the `label`.

Comment: Whats an example q?  Maybe show us the url.

Comment: `$q` may be `anna` or `ann` or `reas john`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output every array in $data where $q is somewhere in 'label'.

```
   <?php

    if( !isset( $_GET["q"] )) return;
    $q = $_GET["q"];

    $data = Array(
        Array(
            'label' => 'anna c13',
            'category' => 'Products'
        ),
        Array(
            'label' => 'anders andersson',
            'category' => 'People'
        ),
        Array(
            'label' => 'andreas johnson',
            'category' => 'People'
        )
    );

    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        if( strpos( $value['label'], $q ) !== false ) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }


    $json = json_encode($result);

    echo $json;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for it. Is this faster than a mysql query? Both ways will have a very big amount of data to search for. In the SQL query I use MATCH AGAINST.

Comment: I'm not sure about MATCH AGAINST, but I know that if comparing this to a mysql query using LIKE, the mysql would be considerably faster.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined keys for your `$data` array - so it automatically take the form of:

```
 array(
    0=>array(...),
    1=>array(...),
    2=>array(...)
  )
```

This means that you're using `strtolower` on an int - so that's probably why it's failing.

Comment: The only `strtolower` I see is on the q variable.  How do you know its failing?

Comment: I have removed the strtolower on my update because I think is not must.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if(strpos($value['label'], $q) !== false){
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry that I can not upvote you, this is because of my low score. When it is necessary to use a remote file for the inputs instead of having them in the jQuery function ?

Comment: @JPampos: What do you mean by _"remote file for the inputs"_?

Comment: I mean to have the json data in a remote file like my example above. In other case, the json are in the jquery function

Comment: @JPampos: In that case you would have to run a loop on the JavaScript. However, that's another question, and you should either figure it out, or at least try to, and ask another question here on SO with your attempt.